# Prove that W_1 * W = I

Tags: linear-algebra

If $W_1= I + C(A-BC)^{-1}\times B$ and $W = I - C A^{-1} B$. How can we prove that always:
$W\times W_1 = I$?
Where $I = n \times n$ identity matrix, $A$ an invertible $n\times n$ matrix, $B$ and $n\times m$ matrices.

Comment: Have you tried to just multiply it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think $$WW_1 B^{-1}(A-BC) =(I-CA^{-1}B)(B^{-1}(A-BC)+C)\\=B^{-1}(A-BC)-CA^{-1}B(B^{-1}(A-BC))+C-CA^{-1}BC\\=B^{-1}A-C-C+CA^{-1}BC+C-CA^{-1}BC\\=B^{-1}A-C=B^{-1}(A-BC)$$ so $WW_1=I$